# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to register user and immediately login using a third party REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have an external API to consume. I am to validate the account using a parameter, register the user if not in existence, then Login with the same detail.

**API:**

https://api.thirdpartycompany.com/UserAccount/api/CustomerDetail?userName=

First, it checks if the customer exists in the external API using userName as parameter.

```
public class GetCustomerDetailDto
{
    public class CustomerDetail
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public object LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I validated the third party API using this method:

interface:

```
public interface IDataUtil
{
    CustomerDetail GetCustomerDetail(string userName);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class DataUtil : IDataUtil
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<DataUtil> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public DataUtil
        (
        IConfiguration config,
        ILogger<DataUtil> logger,
        HttpClient myClient
        )
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
        _myClient = myClient;
    }
    public CustomerDetail GetCustomerDetail(string userName)
    {
        var responseResults = new CustomerDetail();
        _logger.LogError($"responseResults: " + responseResults);
        try
        {
            string custAccountNoUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("custAccountDetailUrl") + userName;
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = _myClient.GetAsync(custAccountNoUrl).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                responseResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDetail>(stringResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return responseResults;
    }
}
```

I have these Auth DTOs:

```
public class UserDto
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}

public class LoginRequestDto
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "The username is required!")]
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password is required!")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResponseDto
{
   public string JwtToken { get; set; }
   public UserDto User { get; set; }
   public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrationRequestDto
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

And now the AuthService.

**IAuthService:**

```
public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request);
    Task<GenericResponseDto<UserDto>> CreateUserAsync(RegistrationRequestDto requestDto);
}
```

**AuthService:**

```
   private async Task<GenericResponseDto<UserDto>> CreateUserAsync(RegistrationRequestDto requestDto)
    {
        var response = new GenericResponseDto<UserDto>();
        var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(requestDto.UserName);
        if (existingUser == null)
        {
            var userDetail = _dataUtil.GetCustomerDetail(requestDto.UserName);
             var user = new AppUser()
            {
                UserName = userDetail.UserName.ToLower().Trim(),
                Email = userDetail.EmailAddress.Trim().ToLower(),
                FirstName = userDetail.FirstName.Trim(),
                LastName = userDetail.LastName.Trim(),
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
            };
            user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Adminpass1");

           if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                var error = string.Join<IdentityError>(", ", result.Errors.ToArray());
                response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto { ErrorCode = 500, Message = "Failed to create user because of the following errors: " + error };
            }
            else
            {
                response.StatusCode = 200;
                response.Result = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
            }

       } else
        {
            response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto { ErrorCode = 400, Message = "This email is already registered!" };
            response.StatusCode = 400;
        }
       return response;
    }

    public async Task<GenericResponseDto<object>> LoginUser(LoginRequestDto request)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
        var response = new GenericResponseDto<object>();

        if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
        {
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

           foreach (var userRole in roles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

           var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

           response.Result = new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                user = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),
                expires = token.ValidTo
            };
            response.StatusCode = 200;

           user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;

           try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto() { ErrorCode = 500, Message = ex.Message };
            }
                            
            return response;
        }

       response.StatusCode = 400;
        response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto { ErrorCode = 400, Message = "Invalid email or password!" };

       return response;
    }
```

In the application, users are not allowed to register manually.

So far, I have created the LoginUser and CreateUserAsync methods.

What I want to achieve is that, when the user tries to login the application checks if username already exists. If yes, it logs in, if no it checks from the external API using UserName as parameter, gets the user data, register the user using CreateUserAsync. Then automatically re-login the user.

How do I achieve this?

NOTE: I am using IdentityDB and EntityFramework

Thanks